# CakePHP Session component error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, fatal-error

In my CakePHP application, when I use another controller's class, I get Session read function error.

`example.com/app/getList` works well
`example.com/seconds/parseList` works well
But `example.com/first/index` gives this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object in
/example.com/app/Controller/AppController.php on line 468
```

Line 468 is this: `$list=$this->Session->read('myList');`

How can I fix this ?

```
class FirstController extends AppController {
    public function index () {
        $Seconds = new SecondsController();
        $Seconds->parseList();
    }
}

class SecondsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Session');

    public function parseList () {
        $output = $this->getList();
        return output;
    }
}

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $uses = array('App', 'Mydata');
    var $components    = array('Session');
    public $helpers = array('Session','Html','Cache');

    public function getList () {
        $list=$this->Session->read('myList');
        return $list;
    }
}
```

Edit: I should mention that `example.com/app/getList` works well. When I run this action independantly it desn't give Session error.

Comment: is AUTO_SESSION set to false in /app/config/core.php.??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call the `constructClasses()` method after manually creating an instance of your controller:

```
$Seconds = new SecondsController();
$Seconds->constructClasses();
```

Comment: My bad. I missed constructClasses. That helped me much. Thank you very much.

Comment: this error cause when we call controller from any other place like Helper. thanks @dhofstet

Answer (score 0):

Did you put `var $components = array('Session');` in your AppController?